# preposition “in”

Tags: prepositions

In this expression, do I need the preposition "in"?

> It seems that we have the same problem like the one we had **in** the last week.

or

> It seems that we have the same problem like the one we had the last week.

Comment: @Buzzyy do you mean something like this: "It seems that we have the same problem ---the one we had in the last week."???

Comment: @Buzzyy Thank you very much

Comment: @Buzzyy - Sorry, that's wrong. We say **the same as**, so it's _the same problem as [the one] we had last week__.

Comment: It's off-topic to ask two questions in one. If you'd like to ask about "as" and "like", you can ask a separate new question. I've edited that line out

Comment: @Buzzyy And your revised sentence includes “like” even though you said you wouldn’t use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to say this is just:

> It seems like we have the same problem as last week.

or:

> It seems like we have the same problem as we did last week.

It is not common to say "the last week" or "in the last week" (although I would argue the former is better than the latter), but instead just "last week." You can specify "as we did last week." but this is strongly implied without the need to add "we did."

Also, "it seems like" is a common phrase and would most commonly be used instead of "it seems like." Another way this could be said, however, is "it seems as if" which is used as a formal replacement for "like."

Furthermore, it could be common to say:

> It seems like we are having the same problem as last week.

"Having" is common if the problem is still current (same as have, so the two versions an be used interchangeably), like if the servers are currently down, and one IT person thinks the issue is the same as a previous issue, that IT person may say to the another "It seems like we are having the same problem as last week."